# How to deal efficiently with lambda AWS and compiled libraries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-lambda

I recently encountered some problems with the integration of a Lambda function using libraries that are not installed by default in the running environment. As results, I followed the procedure explained by AWS in its documentation. The documentation says libraries not installed by default should by uploaded as a zip file and these libraries must be compiled for linux OS.

Since I am on windows, I used the WLS to generate a zip file containing libraries required by my Lambda function. After that, the zip file is uploaded on a S3 and linked to the Lambda function.

The procedure explained above works. However, it is not a procedure that can be automated easily. The automation process is important for maintenance purpose. Is there an automated procedure achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract your dependencies into a [Lambda Layer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/) and if you main Lambda is not heavy just update and test it in the AWS console. Also, as mentioned in the guide, you can use [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) to automate most of the deployment steps and be sure that the code works fine in the Lambda environment.

Answer (score 1):

We use jenkins to create our builds that include paramiko as well as other non native python packages, zip them up and then deploy them to lambda.

We have a base zip stored in artifactory that contains the paramkiko package dependencies as well as a base/blank function.py file that contains our main handler method used in the lambda. This zip was made by making a requirments.txt file with the package name/version in it and running:
pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

This puts all the neccessary files from the dependencies into the directory that command was run from. You can then zip up that directory: zip -r9 ../lambda.zip * -x "bin/*" requirements.txt setup.cfg

You can use this base zip to automate creation of multiple lambdas that use the same packages - you just need to have jenkins copy in the lambda function file you want to use. So every time a jenkins job is run to build/update a lambda function it downloads that base zip we made in the previous step (which as mentioned we store in artifactory but you could store it anywhere) then runs the below command to update that zip with the new lambda:
zip -g ../lambda.zip /path/tocheckedoutlambda/new_lambda_function.py

Jenkins then uses the aws plugin to upload to aws.

This is for python obviously, but you should be able to use similar methods for other languages.

See:
https://alexharv074.github.io/2018/08/18/creating-a-zip-file-for-an-aws-lambda-python-function.html

For more details on making zips for lambda in python.